# My app only works on the platform 2.2

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I made an app, while i made the app i tested it on a AVD device with the platform: 2.2, it works perfect. When i was done, i tried it on my phone with the platform: 4.2.2. Then it said; unfortunately [app name] has stopped. i have tried to run the app on alot of different platforms, but it only works on 2.2. Anyone know how to make the app compatible with all platforms?

Heres my LogCat verbose errors:

```
10-26 19:49:39.364: E/Trace(36): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:49:40.174: E/Trace(94): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:49:49.414: W/Zygote(37): Class not found for preloading: libcore.icu.ErrorCode
10-26 19:50:12.974: E/SoundPool(294): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Lock.ogg
10-26 19:50:12.974: E/SoundPool(294): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Unlock.ogg
10-26 19:50:13.595: E/Trace(294): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:50:17.964: E/Trace(355): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:50:20.254: E/Trace(383): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:50:20.304: E/Trace(398): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:50:21.404: E/Trace(414): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:50:24.334: E/Trace(439): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:50:26.254: E/Trace(457): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:50:33.884: E/Trace(493): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:50:38.004: E/Trace(514): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:50:41.554: E/SoundPool(294): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-26 19:50:41.554: E/SoundPool(294): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-26 19:50:41.554: E/SoundPool(294): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-26 19:50:41.554: E/SoundPool(294): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-26 19:50:41.554: E/SoundPool(294): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-26 19:50:41.566: E/SoundPool(294): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
10-26 19:50:41.566: E/SoundPool(294): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
10-26 19:50:41.566: E/SoundPool(294): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
10-26 19:50:41.566: E/SoundPool(294): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
10-26 19:50:41.566: W/AudioService(294): loadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
10-26 19:50:42.364: E/Trace(534): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:50:42.634: E/Trace(543): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:50:49.246: E/Trace(585): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:50:53.975: W/InputDispatcher(294): channel '4105f7a0 StatusBar (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
10-26 19:50:53.975: W/InputDispatcher(294): channel '41060b28 SearchPanel (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
10-26 19:50:53.984: W/InputDispatcher(294): channel '41030480 NavigationBar (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
10-26 19:50:55.655: E/Trace(612): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:50:58.524: E/Trace(629): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:51:01.645: E/Trace(653): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:51:13.814: D/MmsSmsDatabaseHelper(398): [MmsSmsDb] tableName: threads hasAutoIncrement: CREATE TABLE threads (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,date INTEGER DEFAULT 0,message_count INTEGER DEFAULT 0,recipient_ids TEXT,snippet TEXT,snippet_cs INTEGER DEFAULT 0,read INTEGER DEFAULT 1,type INTEGER DEFAULT 0,error INTEGER DEFAULT 0,has_attachment INTEGER DEFAULT 0) result: true
10-26 19:51:16.234: E/Trace(685): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:51:19.874: E/Trace(706): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:51:17.088: E/Trace(725): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:51:20.598: W/MediaScanner(543): Error opening directory '/mnt/sdcard/', skipping: Permission denied.
10-26 19:51:24.918: E/Trace(759): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:51:25.598: E/Trace(773): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:51:26.558: E/Trace(786): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:51:29.388: E/Trace(815): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 19:51:38.068: E/AndroidRuntime(815): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.traczy2.clickcounter/com.traczy2.clickcounter.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-26 19:51:38.068: E/AndroidRuntime(815): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-26 19:51:38.068: E/AndroidRuntime(815): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

For everyone who says it's something wrong in the line 32 on the activity_main.xml, here is it

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button4"
    android:onClick="button4" />
```

"Button" is line 32

```
10-26 22:29:12.389: E/Trace(36): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:29:13.129: E/Trace(91): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:29:22.729: W/Zygote(37): Class not found for preloading: libcore.icu.ErrorCode
10-26 22:29:49.909: E/SoundPool(289): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Lock.ogg
10-26 22:29:49.929: E/SoundPool(289): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Unlock.ogg
10-26 22:29:50.749: E/Trace(289): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:29:55.379: E/Trace(347): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:29:57.499: W/SocketClient(33): write error (Broken pipe)
10-26 22:29:58.749: E/Trace(387): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:29:58.769: E/Trace(375): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:29:59.569: E/Trace(405): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:30:05.979: E/Trace(436): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:30:06.369: E/Trace(447): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:30:17.409: E/Trace(484): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:30:21.589: E/SoundPool(289): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-26 22:30:21.589: E/SoundPool(289): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-26 22:30:21.599: E/SoundPool(289): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-26 22:30:21.599: E/SoundPool(289): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-26 22:30:21.609: E/SoundPool(289): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-26 22:30:21.609: E/SoundPool(289): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
10-26 22:30:21.609: E/SoundPool(289): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
10-26 22:30:21.609: E/SoundPool(289): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
10-26 22:30:21.699: E/SoundPool(289): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
10-26 22:30:21.699: W/AudioService(289): loadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
10-26 22:30:23.809: E/Trace(517): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:30:26.651: E/Trace(534): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:30:27.019: E/Trace(546): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:30:27.292: E/ActivityManager(289):     5% 509/Error dump: sys: 4.3% user + 0.7% kernel
10-26 22:30:32.558: E/Trace(571): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:30:37.879: E/Trace(592): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:30:44.129: E/Trace(622): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:30:48.080: E/Trace(644): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:30:54.929: E/Trace(665): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:31:00.260: E/Trace(684): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:31:00.843: E/Trace(700): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:31:05.093: W/ActivityManager(289): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/error.apk
10-26 22:31:07.254: D/MmsSmsDatabaseHelper(387): [MmsSmsDb] tableName: threads hasAutoIncrement: CREATE TABLE threads (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,date INTEGER DEFAULT 0,message_count INTEGER DEFAULT 0,recipient_ids TEXT,snippet TEXT,snippet_cs INTEGER DEFAULT 0,read INTEGER DEFAULT 1,type INTEGER DEFAULT 0,error INTEGER DEFAULT 0,has_attachment INTEGER DEFAULT 0) result: true
10-26 22:31:10.045: W/MediaScanner(546): Error opening directory '/mnt/sdcard/', skipping: Permission denied.
10-26 22:31:10.344: W/ActivityManager(289): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/error.apk
10-26 22:31:13.673: E/Trace(738): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:31:14.473: E/Trace(753): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:31:15.514: E/Trace(766): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:31:17.983: E/Trace(795): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 22:31:25.264: E/AndroidRuntime(795): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.traczy2.clickcounter/com.traczy2.clickcounter.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-26 22:31:25.264: E/AndroidRuntime(795): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-26 22:31:25.264: E/AndroidRuntime(795): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

After removing button 3 and 4
```

Comment: Can you plz check your logcat and post that particular error log so that we can know exact root cause of app crash.

Comment: Bets on NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Comment: @Himanshu-HD I posted the logcat verbose errors

Comment: Can you please check for line number 32 in your MainActivity's layout file (xml layout) error occurred there.

Comment: @Himanshu-HD I posted the line number 32

Comment: for now just remove android:background="@drawable/button4" line and check for in your device. If you are not getting error that means issue with your image.

Comment: The app still stops on my device

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the issue is.
One suggestion is to use a trial-and-error approach to investigate which of the fields in your Button mark-up is causing the issue.

I'd try removing the lines that refer to `button3` as a start (so `android:layout_alignLeft` and `android:layout_below`), and if that doesn't help, move onto the others. Are you sure button3 is defined elsewhere in your XML file?

If none of this helps, try removing the whole of this Button from the XML. If you still see the same error then the problem could be more general. (Hand-wavey answer, I know.)

Comment: I've tried to delete the whole button 3 and 4, and their activitys, the app stil stops.

Comment: Thanks for answering btw @Richard Horrocks :)

Comment: Ok, once you've removed the whole of button3 and button4, what line does the logcat error point to?

Comment: I posted the new logcat log on the question, @Richard Horrocks

Comment: Ok, that's pointing at line 41. What's at this line? I notice there's an OutOfMemory error as well. If line 41 includes something that's using an image, then can you check the size of your image files? It's possible they're too big...

Comment: Line 41 what? On activity_main, activity_button1, or? @Richard Horrocks

Comment: Line 41 in the same XML file we were looking at before (the layout associated with MainActivity).

Comment: Ahh, i forgot. line 41 is button 5.

Comment: Maybe its something wrong with all the buttons, and button activitys. I can try to delete all of them, and find out if it works. What do you think?

Comment: Ok, if that button has an image associated with it like the others, I'd suggest looking at the size of the image files. i.e. The drawables being used. How big (in kb) are these?

Comment: Yes!! It worked! i removed all the button pictures, and it worked perfect :) The pics was only 357 kB so thats wierd.. Thank you so much for your help! Now i just have to find some new button pics that will work :)

Comment: Glad we worked out what it was :) There's some detailed information about pictures, and how to load them efficiently, at http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Just following up: Have you had any luck using different/smaller images?